# How to filter fqdn of x.y.c.d where x.y is random, but c.d is fixed?

Tags: bash

```
p66-contacts.fe.apple-dns.net
p39-contacts.fe.apple-dns.net
p11-content.fe.apple-dns.net
p54-content.fe.apple-dns.net
p64-content.fe.apple-dns.net
p17-content.fe.apple-dns.net
gateway.fe.apple-dns.net
p33-availability.fe.apple-dns.net
p35-availability.fe.apple-dns.net
any-applefinance-cache.internal.query.a03.yahoodns.net
apple-weather-yql.media.g04.yahoodns.net
vyvqg.x.incapdns.net
stun1.webrtc.us-east-1.prod.mozaws.net
shavar.prod.mozaws.net
ping.chartbeat.net
d3buumnqdlycz0.cloudfront.net
d3ag4hukkh62yn.cloudfront.net
dg2iu7dxxehbo.cloudfront.net
d1kjqklgpia5go.cloudfront.net
us-u.openx.net
f4.shared.global.fastly.net
online.immi.gov.au
www.border.gov.au
www.zamek-ceskykrumlov.eu
ossuary.eu
www.opera.hu
mng.hu
```

The above are the urls example, I would like to filter out urls where the last two parts(divided by the .) are the same when the matches are greater or equal than 4, then the expected output of that filter will be the below list:

```
apple-dns.net
cloudfront.net
```

but without gov.au, because it only appears twice

sorry, let me change my request a little bit: just filter out the items when last three parts(divided by .) are in common, so `p17-content.fe.apple-dns.net` will be qualified, but `dg2iu7dxxehbo.cloudfront.net` wouldn't qualified; And I tried to use `| rev | cut -d '.' -f -3 | rev`, is that looks good? or any better suggestion?

Comment: Given your revised requirements, why does `cloudfront.net` still appear as part of the desired output?

Comment: Because my revised requirement is capture the items where their last three parts(divided by .) are in common, but `cloudfront.net` only has two parts in common, the code to capture the last three parts is `| rev | cut -d '.' -f -3 |`

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do this in Perl, but it isn't 100% clear that running a Perl script from Bash counts.  However, designing the solution in Perl and then reworking in Bash works for me as a development process.

### Perl solution

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use constant debug => 0;

my %domains2;       # 2-part domains keyed by 3-part domains
my %domains3;       # Count of occurrences of 3-part domains
my $min_count = 4;  # Minimum number of occurrences required

while (<>)
{
    chomp;
    next unless m/(\.[-\w]+\.([-\w]+\.[-\w]+))$/;
    print "OK: $_\n" if debug;
    $domains2{$1} = $2;
    $domains3{$1}++;
}

my %results;
foreach my $dom3 (keys %domains3)
{
    $results{$domains2{$dom3}}++ if $domains3{$dom3} >= $min_count;
}

print join "\n", sort keys %results;
```

This code reads the data lines (`while (<>)`), removes the newline (`chomp;`, then ignores any lines that do not include at least 3 trailing domain components (`next unless`).  While it is deciding whether the line is relevant, it captures the 3-part domain (e.g. `.fe.apple-dns.net`) and the 2-part domain (e.g. `apple-dns.net`).  The `domains3` hash keeps a count of how often the 3-part domain is counted.  The `domains2` hash records the 2-part domain corresponding to each 3-part domain.  The results hash is generated by using the 2-part domains as the key.  This eliminates
duplicates in the 2-part domains list where the same 2-part domain has 2 or more distinct 3-part domains that match.  The final result prints the result of sorting the keys (2-part domain names) from the results hash by joining them with newlines in between.

**Perl minimization**

If you're into Perl minimization, you can use `map` and `grep` to create the results hash (instead of the `foreach` loop):

```
my %results = map  { $domains2{$_} => 1 }
              grep { $domains3{$_} >= $min_count }
              keys %domains3;
```

And once you've done that, it is simple enough to avoid the explicit results hash and combine the printing with the selection:

```
print join "\n", sort keys
                 map  { $domains2{$_} => 1 }
                 grep { $domains3{$_} >= $min_count }
                 keys %domains3;
```

### Extended data set

```
p66-contacts.fe.apple-dns.net
p39-contacts.fe.apple-dns.net
p11-content.fe.apple-dns.net
p54-content.fe.apple-dns.net
p64-content.fe.apple-dns.net
p17-content.fe.apple-dns.net
gateway.fe.apple-dns.net
p33-availability.fe.apple-dns.net
p35-availability.fe.apple-dns.net
any-applefinance-cache.internal.query.a03.yahoodns.net
apple-weather-yql.media.g04.yahoodns.net
vyvqg.x.incapdns.net
stun1.webrtc.us-east-1.prod.mozaws.net
shavar.prod.mozaws.net
ping.chartbeat.net
d3buumnqdlycz0.cloudfront.net
d3ag4hukkh62yn.cloudfront.net
dg2iu7dxxehbo.cloudfront.net
d1kjqklgpia5go.cloudfront.net
us-u.openx.net
f4.shared.global.fastly.net
online.immi.gov.au
www.border.gov.au
www.zamek-ceskykrumlov.eu
ossuary.eu
www.opera.hu
mng.hu
zebra1.za.example.com
zebra3.za.example.com
zebra9.za.example.com
zebra2.za.example.com
zebra4.za.example.com
sasquatch29.us.example.com
sasquatch61.us.example.com
sasquatch68.us.example.com
sasquatch20.us.example.com
sasquatch74.us.example.com
sasquatch60.us.example.com
sasquatch91.us.example.com
```

There are two sub-domains in the `example.com` domain that qualify to be printed, but presumably the `example.com` domain should only be printed once.  Note that the `cloudfare.net` lines are irrelevant; they don't have 4 parts to the domain name.

### Results from Perl

```
apple-dns.net
example.com
```

### Bash solution

This relies on Bash 4.x with support for associative arrays (corresponding to Perl hashes, or Python dictionaries).

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

declare -A domains2       # 2-part domains keyed by 3-part domains
declare -A domains3       # Count of occurrences of 3-part domains
min_count=4

sed -E -n -e '/.*(\.[-a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,}\.([-a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,}\.[-a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,}))$/ s//\1 \2/p' "$@" |
{
while read dom3 dom2
do
    #echo "$dom2   $dom3"
    domains2[$dom3]=$dom2
    ((domains3[$dom3]++))
done

declare -A results
for dom3 in "${!domains3[@]}"
do
    if [ "${domains3[$dom3]}" -ge "$min_count" ]
    then ((results[${domains2[$dom3]}]++))
    fi
done
printf '%s\n' "${!results[@]}" | sort
}
```

This uses the BSD (macOS) `sed -E` option to enable extended regular expressions.  GNU `sed` also recognizes `-E` for the same purpose, though it prefers `-r`.  The extended regular expression matches lines with 4 or more parts to the domain name, and captures and prints the 3-part (`\1`) and 2-part (`\2`) versions of the name.  The rest of the script is a single unit for I/O redirection.  The `while` loop reads the 3-part and 2-part domain names, and does similar counting to the Perl script into the `domains3` and `domains2` associative arrays.  The `for` loop does similar conditional counting of the 2-part domains that have enough separate 3-part entries.  The final `printf … | sort` prints the relevant domains in sorted order.

Funnily enough, the output from the shell script is the same as the output from the Perl script.

This shell script uses `sed` and `sort` as the only external commands (and each is run just once), and uses built-in commands for everything else.  The data file is read just once.  No temporary files are created, so there is no mess to clean up if signals interrupt the script.

Both the Perl and Bash scripts assume that the input data is unique; there are no duplicate entries in the list.  This can be ensured by preprocessing the data file with `sort -u` if need so be.  It would be possible to keep track of the unique full names in the processing, but it adds unnecessary complexity to the script.

Answer (score 0):

(see edit at end to limit consideration to 4-part qualified hostnames)

Well, if you want a one-liner, that relies on bash to handle the parsing, you can use:

```
(( while read -r l; do 
    tmp="${l%.*}"
    tld="${l#"$tmp".}"
    dom="${tmp##*.}"
    echo "$dom.$tld"
done <yourfile.txt ) > temp_file

for i in $(sort -u temp_file); do 
    [ $(grep -c "$i" yourfile.txt) -gt '3' ] && echo "$i"
done

rm temp_file)
```

(**note:** the use of two subshells is intentional to allow copy/paste test)

You can just change `"yourfile.txt"` to your actual filename and then copy/middle-mouse paste the block above in your terminal to test.

**Output**

```
$ ((... above pasted into terminal ...)
apple-dns.net
cloudfront.net
```

**Explanation**

```
( while read -r l; do               ## for each line in your file
    tmp="${l%.*}"                   ## remove the top-level domain
    tld="${l#"$tmp".}"              ## use tmp to save top-level domain
    dom="${tmp##*.}"                ## use tmp to get domain
    echo "$dom.$tld"                ## output "domain.tld" to temp_file
done <yourfile.txt ) > temp_file

for i in $(sort -u temp_file); do   ## for each unique "domain.tld"
    ## check if it appears more than 3 times in yourfile.txt
    [ $(grep -c "$i" yourfile.txt) -gt '3' ] && echo "$i"
done

rm temp_file        ## remove temp_file
```

**note:** you should check for an existing file named `temp_file` before executing the block as it will be overwritten -- or use a proper make temporary file routine.

**note2:** the above `for` loop presume no `spaces` in `"domain.tld"`, if that is a possibility, just turn the `for` into a `while read -r domain; do ... done < <($(sort -u temp_file))`

**Edit to Require `A.B.C.D` (4-Part) Qualified Domain**

Following update of your question, if you want to limit consideration of only 4-part hostnames and ignore those with 3-parts or less, you only need to change a single line to screen 4-part names from `yourfile.txt` in the initial while loop. You can do that with a simply *process substitution* using `grep`, e.g.

```
done < <(grep '..*[.]..*[.]..*[.]..*$' yourfile.txt) ) > temp_file
```

With that limitation, your output would be:

```
$ ((... above with mod pasted into terminal ...)
apple-dns.net
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: This code doesn't insist that the analyzed domains have (at least) four parts, so it reports `cloudfront.net` even though it doesn't meet the (revised) criterion. In fairness, I think the amended information was added (first in comments, somewhat later in an edit to the question) at about the time you produced the answer. Given that this processes the file so often, it doesn't feel efficient to me. That said, although I could measure differences like 61 ms vs 54 ms on the small data files, it would take a significantly larger input file for there to be much of a practical (measurable) effect.

Comment: Yes that's new, the original file had several two part names, e.g. `mng.hu`, and `ossuary.eu` and three part names `www.opera.hu`. That was the whole reason I had to start at the end and work backwards to preserve the `domain.tld` for the two and three part names. If he now only wants the four part names considered, that should make it easier. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, another `grep` solves the 4-part qualified requirement -- and added another subshell to drop it from the 61 ms to the 66 ms range... This is simply one of those issues bash isn't well equipped to solve in the speediest manner. (a short C program loading the file int a buffer or `mmap`ing it would allow the multiple passes needed without penalty of multiple reads of the file).

Comment: One minor puzzle: you use `((` to start your script, but normally `((` indicates the start of an arithmetic expression `((…))` — as does `$((…))`.  However, Bash manages to decide that despite the `((` you must mean 'double sub-shell' and not 'arithmetic expression'.  Do you happen to know if that is a heuristic decision, or because when it reaches the first matching `)` there isn't a second one so it can't be arithmetic?  (Thinking about it, I suspect it is a parsing decision based on the separate `)` closing the `((`.)

Comment: Bash must know it from context. The subshell within a subshell was just to keep the commands together if it were copied/pasted into the terminal. Since `( (while loop) > temp file; rest )` doesn't end in `))`, I suspect your are right. I actually hadn't tried it before considering "Let's try 2 subshells to keep it altogether." You can remove the subshells without affecting operation, but the `while` and `for` will execute -- leaving `rm temp_file` alone on the command line waiting for you to press `[Enter]`. Looks kind of wonky, but it was more to explain the ability to copy/paste to test.

Answer (score 0):

I think this awk do the job

```
awk -F. 'NF>=3{seen[$(NF-1)"."$(NF)]++}END{for(i in seen)if(seen[i]>2)print i}' infile
```

Comment: This lists `cloudfront.net` and it shouldn't.  The revised requirement is modestly complex.  It isn't entirely clear why you chose `>2` rather than `>3`, but that isn't a function of why `cloudfront.net` is printed.

Comment: Try this one awk -F. 'NF>2{seen[$(NF-2)"."$(NF-1)"."$(NF)]++}END{for(i in seen)if(seen[i]>2)print i}' infile. If you look for 3 it's > 2.

Comment: With the sample data shown in my answer, it yields 3 lines of output: `us.example.com
za.example.com
fe.apple-dns.net` -- with the original data, it prints just `fe.apple-dns.net`.  But the output is supposed (I believe) to be just the two-part domain (`example.com` and `apple-dns.net` for the extended data, and just `apple-dns.net` for the original).   Like I said, the requirements are tricky!

Comment: This one is OK with the tricky requirements. awk -F. 'NF>2{s[$(NF-2)FS$(NF-1)FS$(NF)]++}END{for(i in s)if(s[i]>2){sub("[^.]*.","",i);print i}}' infile

Comment: I agree it works on the original data.  If you try it on the data set in my answer, you'd find it lists example.com twice (once for the `*.za.example.com` set and once for the `*.us.example.com` set).  Of course, this is my interpretation of the expected results; the OP has been signally non-communicative about whether any of the offerings are the slightest bit relevant.

Comment: It was more difficult but interesting challenge. awk -F. 'NF>2{if (s[$(NF-2)FS$(NF-1)FS$(NF)]++>2){t[$(NF-1)FS$(NF)]}}END{for(i in t) print i}' infile

Comment: That works for me.  My browser suddenly showed my your previous offering after I'd submitted this — I'll offer you this as meeting the criteria: `awk -F. '
NF > 3 { count[$(NF-2) "." $(NF-1) "." $NF]++ }
END { for (i in count) if (count[i] >= 4) { sub(/^[^.]+\./, "", i); domains[i]++ }
      for (i in domains) print i
    }'` — I might not have bothered with it had I seen your last entry before adding this.